# i want to know what the second for does with the k

Tags: python

```py
for k in range(2, 10):
    for a in range(2, k):
        if k % a == 0:
            print(k, "equals", a, "*", k // a)
            break
    else:
        print(k, "is a prime number")
```

I was trying to understand the second for loop, i searched for help on internet and it says the k in the second for is k -1 (2-1) is that true? why it's not 2 to 9, like in the first for loop. That is all my question. i Just want to know what a equals.

I tried to understand what the k is in the second for loop

Comment: What is not clear in [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) documentation?

Comment: Why would it be `2` to `9` if `k` is not `9` in most of the iterations?

Comment: The first loop goes from 2 to 9.  The second loop goes from 2 to whatever the current value of `k` is from the first loop.

Comment: then, it will always be for a in range(2, 2) then range(2, 3) range (2, 4) until it reaches 9? or am i wrong?

Comment: Moved my comment to an answer to share an example.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `k` is set in each iteration of the first loop. The first loop iterates 8 times.

In the first iteration, the value of `k` is `2`. So in that first iteration the second for loop is:

```
for a in range(2, 2):
```

In the second iteration the value of `k` is `3`. So in that second iteration the second for loop is

```
for a in range(2, 3):
```

and so on.

---

In short, the second `for` loop is created, iterated upon, and destroyed once every time the first loop iterates.

It may help to set up a minimal example that outputs information from inside the loops:

```
for k in range(1,5):
  print(f'The Value of k is {k}')
  for a in range(1,k):
    print(f'The value of k is still {k} and the value of a is {a}')
```

Which yields:

```
The Value of k is 1
The Value of k is 2
The value of k is still 2 and the value of a is 1
The Value of k is 3
The value of k is still 3 and the value of a is 1
The value of k is still 3 and the value of a is 2
The Value of k is 4
The value of k is still 4 and the value of a is 1
The value of k is still 4 and the value of a is 2
The value of k is still 4 and the value of a is 3
```